# Resize the screen in GWT

Tags: gwt

I am developing a GWT Web application and I would like to include the resize capability into the container. For that, I am implementing a combination of Vertical and Horizontal Panels within a FlowPanel which is resizable. Well, the code for the resize method is the following:

```
Window.addResizeHandler(new ResizeHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onResize(ResizeEvent event) {   
        flowPanel.setHeight(event.getHeight()+"px"); 
        flowPanel.setWidth(event.getWidth()+"px");
    }
});
```

However, when I change the size of the windows, the size of the web elements does not change. Do you know how to implement it?

Thank you very much in advance!!!

Comment: You don't need String.valueOf(): when you add a String ("px") to a int, the result is a String.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to review your layout solution. There are very few cases when you need to use a ResizeHandler. Typically, you can achieve a desired layout either by using a LayoutPanel (or Horizontal/Vertical panels) that automatically resize with the window, or by using CSS. Then your layout will respond well to any changes in a browser window, and you don't need to write any code for that to happen.

EDIT:

In order for a widget to resize automatically, the parent widget must implement ProvidesResize, and the child widget must implement Resizable. FlowPanel does not implement either. Once you use it, the chain of resizing events is broken.

Typically, I use a LayoutPanel for my outmost container. It occupies the entire browser window when added to the RootPanel, and it adjusts with the Window. Vertical and Horizontal panels are similar.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. In fact, I am using a combination of Vertical and Horizontal panels which are all included in a Flow Panel and then inserted in the Root Panel. I was expecting a automatic resize, but it does not work. These elements have not been established with a default size (i.e. method setSize())

Comment: However, when I zoom in/out the Windows both with the keyboard and mouse scroll the content is resized, but when I adapt the size of the browser window by the pointer or the buttons on the top of the browser it does not work

Answer (score 1):

use,

```
window.getClientWidth();
window.getClientHeight();
```

Based on your component size you can -/+ px and use.

Comment: Use sysout or window.alert(Window.getClientWidth());
it will show the client screen width and height based on that you can set height and width of your components.

Comment: Yes, it was done and we can see how the values are changing. In fact, I have tested right now setting the size of the Flow Panel to 10px when the event resize handler is raised, but no answer from the GUI, although we have a pop-up with the new size...